# Better way to implement arithmetic operator overloads with a n-dimensional C++ Vector class?

Tags: c++, performance, vector

I have my own mathematical Vector class that I use in my code. I have a new need to generalize my vector class to n dimensions instead of just two.

My question is, what's the best way to implement the operator overloads, and is there a significant overhead to doing this?

I now store the values in an array

```
double *vals;
....
vals = new double[dimension];
```

With this, I implement the + operator like so:

```
Vector Vector::operator+(Vector v) 
{
    Vector ret = Vector(dimension);
    for (int i = 0; i < dimension; i ++)
    {
        ret.vals[i] = vals[i] + v.vals[i];
    }
}
```

This operation will be done a LOT and has to run fast. Is this significantly worse than the old version (as far as speed)?

```
Vector Vector::operator+(Vector v) {
    return Vector(x + v.x, y + v.y);
}
```

Thanks for any input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a fast vector class then use templates for the size:

```
template<std::size_t size>
class Vector {
  double data[size];
public:
  double& operator[](std::size_t x) { return data[x]; }
};

template<std::size_t size>
Vector<size> operator+(Vector<size> lhs, const Vector<size>& rhs) {
  for (std::size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    lhs[i] += rhs[i];
  return lhs;
}
```

Having them be dynamic size is only unnecessary if you want to re-size them, or if they are incredibly large.

There are ways to get much faster than this, such as SSE. You should use a dedicated math library if you want something highly optimized.

Answer (score 1):

First, I would suggest passing your operand by *reference* instead of by value to avoid an unnecessary object copy:

```
Vector Vector::operator+(const Vector &v) {
```

Second, most compilers implement [Return Value Optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization) which will help eliminate the local `ret` in your multidimensional implementation.

The best approach, of course, is to implement your code, benchmark it, and *then* apply optimisations where necessary. Scott Meyers' [Effective C++](http://www.aristeia.com/books.html) is an excellent reference for the sort of thing you're attempting to do here.

Comment: RVO wont be invoked in this particular example.

Comment: Well it won't if it doesn't actually `return ret;` ... but assuming `ret` is returned, why wouldn't it?